# Why is the Tomcat BIO Connector inefficient?

Tags: java, tomcat

While studying Spring, I was curious about how Multi-Thread works when many users connect at the same time. I realized that it is Tomcat, not Spring, that receives requests and allocates threads. Tomcat provides two ways to do this: BIO connector and NIO connector, and Tomcat decided to use NIO instead of BIO for performance reasons. However, I had a hard time understanding the reason for the performance degradation when using BIO.

#### BIO Connector

- It works in a blocking way.
- When a request arrives, it allocates a thread from the thread pool and maps it to the request.
- When the request ends, it returns the thread.

#### NIO Connector

- It works in a non-blocking way.
- The poller thread loops through the socket channel in a non-blocking manner and maps a thread to the request that arrives.

#### Question

- It is said that the BIO method affects performance **due to the idle time of the allocated threads** and **requires more threads** than the NIO method.
- In order for the NIO method to be beneficial, **blocking must occur after the request is mapped to a thread**. (so that the thread has idle time).
- However, from the moment a Request is assigned to a Thread, the Thread will behave as defined by the Spring Container, so there will be no idle time.

#### First guess

Tomcat uses `socket.accept` to recognize a request. If the point at which `socket.accept` recognizes a request is **when the first packet of the request arrives**, rather than **when the request arrives in its entirety from the network**, then there may be a delay after assigning a thread to the request, waiting for the remaining packets to arrive.

Putting aside whether this assumption is correct for now, I wonder if the delay is too small to justify NIO for this reason alone, and if the overhead is too high.

#### Second guess

If tomcat allocates a thread to the created socket channel and polls for requests in a blocking manner, the idle time of the thread will be significant even if there is no immediate connection (because even if there is no connection, the thread is allocated and blocked until the next connection). In this case, the statement **"When a request arrives, a thread is allocated from the thread pool, and when the request is resolved, the thread is returned"** is **incorrect**. This is because **"a thread is allocated at the time the socket channel is created, and once created, the socket channel is persisted until the server is shut down, so the allocated thread is not returned to the pool."**

If this were the case, I could sympathize with the need for an NIO connector. However, in this case, the need for a thread pool is questionable.

#### Third guess

The BIO Connector is maintained in multiple threads. The number of threads is equal to the number of socket channels created. Later, when all the created channels are in use, new threads are created and allocated for new requests, increasing the number of channels. **The threads of the BIO Connector managed in this way are completely separate from the threads that will resolve requests in Spring**.

Therefore, there is no difference in the allocation/return time and the number of threads that will be created to act as Spring Containers, whether BIO or NIO. Only the number of own Threads of BIO Connector and NIO Connector decreases from N (number of socket channels) to 1 (Selector) and their behavior changes from Blocking to Non-Blocking.

#### Fourth guess

BIO allocates a thread from the moment a request arrives, and does not return the thread when it resolves the request. **It waits for the connection to close before deallocating the thread.**

**NIO does not map a thread to a request**, but rather queues up the job requested by the request and **assigns that job to the thread**. When the thread resolves the job, it is returned directly to the pool **without waiting for the connection to close**. If there are additional requests, the poller will create the job again, queue it, and assign it to an idle thread.

#### Cleanup

Tomcat introduced the NIO connector because of problems with the BIO connector. But what exactly was wrong with the BIO connector? If it allocates a thread on request arrival and returns a thread on resolve, it's not a problem by any stretch of the imagination. If it allocates a thread on socket channel creation and doesn't return the thread when the request is resolved, it's definitely a performance issue. But if that's really the case, there is no process of returning and reusing threads, so thread pools are pointless. So are threads in Tomcat Connector and threads in Spring Container separate concepts? Maybe the difference between BIO and NIO is the difference between mapping a request to a thread or mapping the job that the request requires to a thread?

I'm new to Spring, so maybe I'm asking too many obvious questions, or maybe I'm just being silly. Thank you for reading this long post and I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: "[BIO connector] When a request arrives, it allocates a thread from the thread pool and maps it to the request": false. A thread is permanently allocated to the connection. There is no other way it can work. Duplicate, and nothing to do with Spring whatsoever.

Comment: @user207421 I read through the questions you guided me to, and it looks like my 4th guess was correct. Thanks for the advice!